# Sight is to Visualisation as Sound is to?

Tags: single-word-requests

Unsure that the word exists, given our preference for sight to convey abstract information rather than sound, but I was hoping one of you might know?

Comment: _Visualization_ means imagining a visual experience, rather than having one. Are you asking about imaginary soundscapes? Don't forget, human vision perceives outlines and imposes order on its input, whereas human sound perception does not form images, except perhaps in imagination.

Comment: I could have sworn the word was _auralization_, but I can't find that word in any dictionary.

Comment: Could you give the context where you plan to use the word?

Comment: Your categories don't seem to match to me. Sight is normally considered a sense, but the sense of sound is hearing, not sound.

Comment: If a sight is 'visualised,' a sound might be 'heard in the mind,'  'imagined,' or a sequence might be '**composed**.' or 'heard as an ear-worm.' But none of them readily form abstract nouns.

Comment: @curiosdanny: I think you read "sight" as referring only to the sense of seeing, whereas OP might have meant it in the sense of "a thing seen". So this IS analogous to a sound; i.e. a thing heard.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are mentioning 'abstract information' I think you might use the word

*[sonification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonification):*

> *Sonification is the use of non-speech audio to convey information or perceptualize data.[1] Auditory perception has advantages in temporal, spatial, amplitude, and frequency resolution that open possibilities as an alternative or complement to visualization techniques.* (Wikipedia).

[This article](http://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/15987335.pdf) by Thomas Hermann deals with the definition of 'sonification' and suggests that it should be used as an analogue to 'visualisation':

> ... *we suggest using sonification with the same level of generality as the term visualization is used in visual display.*

---

P.S. SomethingDarks's suggestion helped with finding this word, so thank you. I think [auralization](http://www.diracdelta.co.uk/science/source/a/u/auralization/source.html#.VV6aMkbD_LJ) is something a bit different, though.

Answer (score 0):

> Visualisation

Visualisation is an act of the mind, not a direct result of sensory input. One can easily "visualise" a scene or object based on sound or touch.

Comment: I think you're probably right, but this could use a psych/neuro ref.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest **sounding out**.

Eg.

> I'm thinking we could put the tree in front of the sun, I'm trying to visualise this.
>
> I'm thinking I could talk about his contributions to the company, and then his character as the office joke. I'm trying to sound this out.

Answer (score 0):

Sight is to visualization as sound is to *[audiation](https://giml.org/mlt/audiation/)*.

> *Audiation* is the foundation of musicianship. It takes place when we
>   hear and comprehend music for which the sound is no longer or may
>   never have been present.

Or to put it [another way](https://www.musical-u.com/learn/the-secret-music-practice-skill-audiation/):

> Audiation is to sound what visualization is to images.